# Spring Roo 1.2: Using Spring Roo just to create controller, no jspx file

Tags: json, google-app-engine, rest, jquery-mobile, spring-roo

I am trying to create a RAD jquery mobile application generator that sits on a roo generate gae project.  I've written the generator code that finds all jpa entities and then creates a full jquery mobile application over the found entities utilizing REST/JSON services created with roo.  Similar to what roo `web mvc` does with the dojo web app.  I'm trying to find a way to only create the REST/JSON controller and not all the view stuff (jspx/tagx/tiles/etc) as they do not deploy to gae. Does anyone know if this is possible without editing the roo plugin directly?

```
project --topLevelPackage com.testpackage --java 6 --projectName testproject
persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Company --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --sizeMax 50
service --interface ~.service.CompanyService
json add --class ~.domain.Company
controller all --package ~.controller.CompanyController <---- creates the controller and all the unwanted web stuff
```

Any thought would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: ended up forking the addon source code. modified it so the files are not copied over.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to report that this is possible with Spring Roo 1.2.5.

```
project --topLevelPackage com.example.jukebox
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY 
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Song
field string --fieldName title
json add 
web mvc json setup
web mvc json all
exit
```

Spin up a Jetty server with `mvn jetty:run`.

Now, you can POST a song:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"title":"Ride Around Shining"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/jukebox/songs
```

Or GET a list of all songs: `curl http://localhost:8080/jukebox/songs`

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Ride Around Shining","version":0}]
```

Or GET a song by id: `curl http://localhost:8080/jukebox/songs/1`

```
{"id":1,"title":"Ride Around Shining","version":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up forking the roo web addon source code.  Made the modification so the jspx files were not copied over.